# To hide the search box from Mysite (SP2013 on premise)

Tags: mysite, style

Is there a centralized CSS file for SP2013 MySite? We would like to hide all the search box under mysite pages. Can we do it without update the sites 1 by 1? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can upload custom css file in HTML MasterPage, just before `</head`> tag and set

```
#SearchBox{
    display:none!important;
}
```

this will remove all search boxes from the site.

[image]then create css file

[image]

place it in master page

[image]

and this is output
[image]

All of this is done with SharePoint designer, but I am not sure is this you are looking for.

Best is to create custom MasterPage and do all this, 
But if there are just some pages you need to remove searchbox, you can add

```
<script>
 var x =$(location).attr('href');
        switch(x){
    case "http://yoururl.com/Pages/somepage.aspx":
        $('body').addClass('classOne');
        break;
    case "http://yoururl.com/Pages/smoeanotherpage.aspx":
        $('body').addClass('classTwo');
        break;
        }
</script>
```

at the bottom of body tag of MasterPage and inside of css now you select

```
.classTwo #SearchBox{
display:none;
}
```

Comment: Where can I find Mysitehost's HTML MasterPage and related CSS files?

Comment: You do this with sharepoint designer, open your site by entering url. There are section MasterPages on right side, and css foldef and file you can create by yourself anywhere in that MasterPage section,
After you create css file and locate your MasterPage
add link to css at the bottom of <head> tag in MasterPage.

Comment: Our mysitehost web application is http://my.sp.com. I connect to it with farm admin account and found mysite15.master. It is the file I should work on? When I try to save it throw me a warning I don't understand. Any consequence I should aware before change? Thanks.

Comment: best practice is to create custom masterpage when editing this things.

Comment: So I should create a custom.Master and then apply the new master using SPD?

Comment: Yes.Then you can do this customization.

Comment: The change would be global and all new users' mysite (which is not created at the moment) will use the customized Master?

Comment: Last question, may I know which permission role I should use to update the MySiteHost master page?